# constructing objects extending current class using static method

Tags: java, static, abstract

I have an abstract class "TapeObject" extended by "Wall" and "Gate". Each TapeObject is identified by it's name (set in constructor).

```
public static TapeObject create(String format) {
    if (format.length() != 1) {
        return null;
    }
    TapeObject tmpobj;
    if (format.equals("w")) {
        return tmpobj = new Wall (this.name);
    }
    if (format.equals("g")) {
        return tmpobj = new Gate (this.name);    
    }
    return null;
}
```

Why my IDE says "cannot find symbol Wall/Gate" and also "non-static variable name cannot be referenced from a static context"? I'm new to java. How can I create and return the objects properly? The method *must* remain static.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot reference class/instance variables from a static method because a static method is not associated with a specific instance of its class. You are referring to `name` inside a static method, but for example, if I say

`MyClass.create()` I did this without instantiating an object of type `MyClass`, so without instantiation, Java does not reserve any space in memory for the `name` variable

Static methods are meant to be used as helper or util methods.

Also, it is odd that you have a method called `create` Creation is referred to as instantiation, and it is the job of the `constructor` to handle this logic.

You can try this in your class that is invoking this `create` method

```
TapeObject to1;
if (format == "w") {
  to1 = new Wall("Berlin Wall")
}
```

Your `Wall` constructor should be as follows:

```
public Wall(String name) {
  super(name); // passes the name field to your superclass
}
```

Comment: Well, it's meant to be used like this: `TapeObject mygate = TapeObject.create("g");` should do the same like `TapeObject mygate = new Gate ("mygate");`

Comment: @MarekTeuchner If you are trying to handle construction of your subclasses, this should be handled by their respective constructors

Comment: But I know, that this method must exist, can't be abstract, and must return correct TapeObject -> So I cannot specify it in my subclasses.

Comment: There is no way that you can use `this.name` inside of a static method. Try handling this logic in the class that is invoking this method. Editing my answer to explain

Comment: It's more clear to me, thanks. I wanted somehow to set the "name" parameter same as object variable name, but as I see, it's not possible in this case. So I reworked it.

Comment: @MarekTeuchner Your welcome, please upvote and accept this answer if you feel it helped you.